# Using PHP to show "Next" an "Previous" in pagination

Tags: php, pagination

I am using the following code:

```
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table LEFT JOIN table2 
   ON table.field = table2.field WHERE ( table.field = '$pid' ) 
   AND ( table.field5 LIKE '%$q%' OR table.field3 LIKE '%$q%' 
    OR table2.field2 LIKE '%$q%' )");


     if (empty($what)) {

      $countpls = "0";
      } else {

     $countpls = mysql_num_rows($result);
      }


<?php
if ($countpls > 10) {
    echo '<a id=pgnvg href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pg=' . ($startrow + 20) . '&q=' . ($what) . '">Next</a>';
} else {
    echo "";
}

$prev = $startrow - 20;

//only print a "Previous" link if a "Next" was clicked
if ($prev >= 0) {
    echo '<a id=pgnvg2 href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pg=' . $prev . '&q=' . ($what) . '">Previous</a>';
} else {
    echo "";
}
?>
```

I want the next to show only if there are more entries to show and previous only if there are more entries to circle back to.  It works on the first page bt then on the last page Next shows despite teh fact that there are no more results to show.

I tried adding the 'else' but its still not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($countpls > 0){
    $pg = $_POST['pg']?$_POST['pg']:1;

    //if it's not the first page...
    if($pg>1){
        echo '<a id="pgnvg" href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pg='.($pg-1).'&q='.$what.'">Previous</a>';
    }
    //if you have more registers to show...
    if(($countpls-(($pg-1)*10))>10){
     echo '<a id="pgnvg" href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pg='.($pg+1).'&q='.$what.'">Next</a>';
    }
}
```

In order to calculate your offset to use in queries, use this:

```
$offset = ($_POST['pg']-1)*10;
```

Comment: where do i implement the $offset.  your query worked but only for the first 2 pages.  there are 28 results so the first page showed 10 then then next showed 10 and the 2nd page only have teh previous option not the next one...

Comment: You will have to use in your query: LIMIT 10 OFFSET $offset. Also, if you are using 10 items per page then change that 20 for 10. I'll fix it on the code here.

Comment: You will have to use in your SQL query: `LIMIT 10 OFFSET $offset`.

Comment: ok when i use that it says Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-10' at line 1

Comment: Ok, consider opening another question with your sql code for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you would provide the code that's setting `$countpls`. That might be the part that's causing the problem. Also, the else's are unnecessary. However, try this:

```
if($countpls - $startrow > 20)
{
    echo '<a id=pgnvg href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pg='.($startrow+20).'&q='.($what).'">Next</a>';
}
```

Comment: sorry added it to the question now. please check now.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would do you good if you followed a tutorial to grasp the basic concepts. It even comes with the example that could either 1.) replace your current pagination or 2.) fix it.

http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination